# "blob".then is not a function when trying to generate pdf in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am sending the below response from my REST Api .

```
{
"value": "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",
"transid": "transid"
```

}

I am trying to convert the value which is byte data to pdf using React js.

Below is my implementation:

```
 handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
let url = "http://localhost:8080/getPDF"
 fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.transId),
     })
responseType: 'blob'
.then(response => {
//Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
    const file = new Blob(
      [response.value], 
      {type: 'application/pdf'});
//Build a URL from the file
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
//Open the URL on new Window
    window.open(fileURL);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
  };
```

But I am getting the following error.Can anyone please suggest where I am going wrong?

> Uncaught TypeError: "blob".then is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `.then()` after a string ([must follow a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)). You probably meant this line `responseType: 'blob'` to be one line higher up, inside the object?

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let url = "http://localhost:8080/getPDF"
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.transId),
    responseType: 'blob' // <-- MOVE THIS LINE INTO REQUEST
  })
  .then(response => {
  //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
      const file = new Blob(
        [response.value], 
        {type: 'application/pdf'});
  //Build a URL from the file
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  //Open the URL on new Window
      window.open(fileURL);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  });
};
```